# Verify the multiplication of two absolute abelian group elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

**Question**
Given that $a$ and $b$ belong to an Abelian group and that $|a|=6$ and $|b|=6$, what can you say about $|ab|$?

**My solution**
$$
|a|=6 \\
a=6 \\
a^6=e
$$
similarly:
$$
|b|=6 \\
b=6 \\
b^6=e
$$
hence
$$
|ab|=(ab) \\
(ab)=(ab)^6=a^6b^6=ee=e
$$
therefore, $|ab|=6$, and $ab$ belongs to $G$.

Q: Pls what sis I do wrong in answering the question???

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Saying that $|a|=6$ means that $a^6=e$ and $a^k\ne e$, for $0<k<6$.

What can you say about $|ab|$? Well,
$$
(ab)^6=a^6b^6=ee=e
$$
so $|ab|$ is a divisor of $6$. Why? This is a basic property of the order of elements in a group.

Now, try your hand at finding examples with $|a|=6$, $|b|=6$ and

1. $|ab|=1$
2. $|ab|=2$
3. $|ab|=3$
4. $|ab|=6$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example showing what you did wrong. Let $G=C_6$ the cyclic group of order $6$, and $a$ a generator. Then $|a|=6$. Now take $b=a^{-1}$. Then also $b$ is a generator, hence $|b|=6$. However $ab=aa^{-1}=e$ so that $|ab|=|e|=1$, contradicting $|ab|=6$.

Comment: are you saying |ab| != 6?

Comment: Yes, I am saying that $|ab|=1\neq 6$.